# Find the most repeated row in a MATLAB matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix, row, mode

I am looking for a function to find the most repeated (i.e. modal) rows of a matrix in MATLAB. Something like:

```
>> A = [0, 1; 2, 3; 0, 1; 3, 4]

A =

 0     1
 2     3
 0     1
 3     4
```

Then running:

```
>> mode(A, 'rows')
```

would return `[0, 1]`, ideally with a second output giving the indexes where this row occurred (i.e. `[1, 3]'`.)

Does anyone know of such a function?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use [UNIQUE](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/unique.html) to get unique row indices, and then call [MODE](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/mode.html) on them.

```
[uA,~,uIdx] = unique(A,'rows');
modeIdx = mode(uIdx);
modeRow = uA(modeIdx,:) %# the first output argument
whereIdx = find(uIdx==modeIdx) %# the second output argument
```

Comment: Thanks. I think the last line should be something like: `whereIdx = find(uIdx(modeIdx)==uIdx)` though.

Comment: @Bill Cheatham: Yes, of course. That's what I get for adding a line *after* testing.

Comment: @sinoTrinity: Thanks. Solution has been fixed.

Comment: No problem. There may be still something wrong with the last statement. whereIdx should be index of A, not uA as it is now, right?

Comment: @Jonas: I believe you meant to say: `whereIdx = find(uIdx==modeIdx)`

Answer (score 2):

The answer may not be right. Try A = [2, 3; 0, 1; 3, 4; 0, 1].
It should be the following:

```
[a, b, uIdx] = unique(A,'rows');
modeIdx = mode(uIdx);
modeRow = a(modeIdx,:) %# the first output argument
whereIdx = find(ismember(A, modeRow, 'rows'))  %# the second output argument
```